# networkx.GraphMatcher v 1.8

Tags: python, networkx

Is the python module - networkx.GraphMatcher not implemented in version 1.8.1? 
I am running networkx through macports and it doesnt find the GraphMatcher module. 
Also, I seem not to find a documentation for 1.8 while it exists for 1.6

exists:
    init.html">http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.6/reference/generated/networkx.GraphMatcher.**init**.html

does not exist
    init.html">http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.8/reference/generated/networkx.GraphMatcher.**init**.html

Cheers,
EL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetworkX documentation is on Github (you have linked to an old version).  See e.g. http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.isomorphism.html